# Dompdf page_text using canvas is missing on pages past the first page

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

I'm trying to get page counters in the footer. For this I'm using the option that uses the `getCanvas()->page_text()` function in php (opposed to the script version which I couldn't get to display anything at all). The problem is that `1/1` is properly shown on the first page but not on any additional pages rendered.

It seems to be that Dompdf isn't properly registering that it has created multiple pages as `PAGE_COUNT` shown on the first footer will also remain at `1` even if the pdf has multiple pages.

If I add pages using the `page-break-after` CSS meant for Dompdf it has no effect in solving the issue at hand (and it doesn't increase `PAGE_COUNT`).

```
class PdfGenerator
{

    public static function generate($type, $resource, $is_stored = false)
    {
        $data = self::getData($type, $resource);
        $pdf = Pdf::loadView('pdf/' . $type, $data);
        
        $font =  $pdf->getFontMetrics()->getFont("helvetica", "normal");
        $canvas = $pdf->getCanvas();
        $canvas->page_text(540, 785, "{PAGE_NUM} / {PAGE_COUNT}", $font, 10, array(0, 0, 0));

        if ($is_stored) {
            $file_name = $type . ' ' . $resource->display_name;
            $pdf->save(storage_path('pdf').'/' . $file_name . '.pdf');
        }

        return $pdf;
    }
}
```

Most of the main content consists of a single table consisting of multiple merged headers and data (for easier consistent layout). The table contents are parsed by row number and individual row height for splitting it up neatly across multiple pages in an array to be processed in the blade.

So I just let the table spill over into following pages in a controlled manner, which is creating multiple pages perfectly fine in the final PDF generated, aside from the single detail of the missing `page_text` past the first page.

From what documentation I've read this method (opposed to using the CSS) should not keep Dompdf from properly registering the increased page count, so I'm at the end of my rope in solving this.

```
<html>
    <head>
        {{-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"> --}}
        @include('pdf/partials/style')
       
    </head>
    <body>

        {{-- HEADER & FOOTER --}}
        <header>@include('pdf/partials/table-header-invoice')</header>
        <footer>@include('pdf/partials/table-footer-invoice')</footer>

        <main>
            {{-- TITLE --}}
            <h1>{{ucFirst(__('invoice', [], $locale))}}</h1>

            {{-- DETAILS TABLE--}}
            @include('pdf/partials/table-details-invoice')
            <br>

            {{-- CONTENTS TABLE --}}
            @foreach ($pages_array as $page)
                <table style="font-size: 14px">
                    @foreach ($page as $content_type => $contents)
                        @include('pdf/partials/theader-' . $content_type)
                        @include('pdf/partials/tbody-' . $content_type)
                        <br>
                    @endforeach
                </table>
            @endforeach
                
            {{-- <p style="page-break-after: always;"></p>
            <p style="page-break-after: never;"></p> --}}
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because PHP doesn't know the total page number. You have to `output()` first to get the total number and then reuse `output()` to get the final version. Like this:

```
$pdf->output();
$font =  $pdf->getFontMetrics()->getFont("helvetica", "normal");
$pdf->getCanvas()->page_text(522, 770, "Page {PAGE_NUM} / {PAGE_COUNT}", $font, 8, array(.5,.5,.5));

Storage::disk('internal')->put(
  'files/' . $fileName,
  $pdf->output()
);
```